# why tell me illegal pid when kill process

Tags: linux

Now I am using this script to restart my process:

```
PID=`ps -ef|grep -w ${APP_NAME}|grep -v grep|cut -c 9-15`
if [[ ${PID} -gt 1 ]]; then
  kill -9 ${PID}
else
  echo "Process not found"
fi
```

but when I run this script in remote server from GitHub Actions,shows this error:

```
======CMD======
cd /opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs
. /opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh

======END======
err: +/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:13> JAVA_HOME=/***/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.11.hs-adpt 
err: +/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:14> APP_HOME=/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs 
err: +/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:15> APP_NAME=dolphin-acientbay-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
err: +/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:17> PID=+/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:17> ps -ef
err: +/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:17> PID=+/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:17> grep -w dolphin-acientbay-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
err: +/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:17> PID=+/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:17> grep -v grep
err: +/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:17> PID=+/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:17> cut -c 9-15
err: +/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:17> PID=' 19882 ' 
2021/05/30 11:46:21 Process exited with status 1
err: +/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:18> [[ ' 19882 ' -gt 1 ]]
err: +/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:19> kill -9 ' 19882 '
err: /opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:kill:19: illegal pid:  19882
```

this is the full script of `upgrade.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -u

set -e

set -x

JAVA_HOME="/root/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.11.hs-adpt"
APP_HOME="/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs"
APP_NAME="dolphin-acientbay-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

PID=`ps -ef|grep -w ${APP_NAME}|grep -v grep|cut -c 9-15`
if [[ ${PID} -gt 1 ]]; then
  kill -9 ${PID}
else
  echo "Process not found"
fi

sleep 5

count=`ps -ef | grep ${APP_NAME} | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
if [[ ${count} -lt 1 ]]; then
  nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Xmx128M -Xms128M -jar \
  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=0.0.0.0:5021 \
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/ \
  ${APP_HOME}/${APP_NAME} >> ./acientbay.log &
  sleep 5
else
  echo "process aready exists!"
  exit 1
fi
```

I have tried to tweak the kill process command like this(the xargs trim the white space of pid) to remove the spaces of pid:

```
 echo "${PID}" | xargs | kill -9
```

it tell me :

```
err: /opt/apps/dolphin-acientbay/libs/upgrade.sh:kill:19: not enough arguments
```

Comment: It seems to be telling you that the sequence `space 1 9 8 8 2 space` is not a number. What version of BASH is being invoked?

Comment: You could remove the spaces around the PID, for example with `tr -d`.

Comment: Show us the actual script and the actual error messages. At least one of them is obviously doctored since the line numbers don't match.

Comment: @berndbausch The unquoted expansion of `${PID}` already takes care of removing spaces (unless `IFS` has been changed).

Comment: I think spaces may not make this command failed, the command would success even through have spaces.

Comment: It *looks* like the script is actually being run by `zsh` (where unquoted expansions are not subject to word splitting by default)...

Comment: it should be the problem @ steeldriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the source of your problem:

```
PID=`ps -ef|grep -w ${APP_NAME}|grep -v grep|cut -c 9-15`
```

1. Double-quote your variables when you use them.  e.g. "$APP_NAME" or "${APP_NAME}".

   BTW, the curly-braces are only needed when you need to disambiguate a variable from other text in a string.  e.g. if the variable was actually `$APP` but you needed to use it in a string with `_NAME`, you'd use `"${APP}_NAME"` - that would prevent `_NAME` from being interpreted by the shell as being part of the variable name.
2. You're using backticks instead of `$()`.  They've been deprecated for years, and for good reason.  They're not the cause of the problem here, just a bad habit you need to quit.
3. `cut` is not a good tool for extracting fields that can be delimited by 1-or-more characters.  It's only good when there is one (and exactly one) delimiter between fields.  Many text files use 1 or more spaces (and/or tabs and/or other white-space characters) as field delimiters and can not easily be processed with `cut`.  Use `awk` or `perl` instead.

   Your use of `cut -c 9-15` is causing at least one extra space character to be captured in $PID.   To extract a PID from `ps -ef`, use `awk '{print $2}'` instead of `cut -c 9-15`.
4. Use `pgrep "$APP_NAME"` to get the PID of a process by name.  Or `pgrep -f "$APP_NAME"` if the
   string you're searching for is an argument (e.g. when the script's name is passed as an arg to an interpreter).

   Cargo-culting `ps | grep ... | grep -v grep` has been obsolete for decades now - and was never a good way to do it, anyway.   `ps -ef | awk '/[p]rocess_name/ {print $2}'` was always a better way (putting a `[]` around the first character of the pattern prevents awk, or grep, or whatever, from matching itself in the ps output), but even that is now obsolete with `pgrep`.

   `ps` itself has a `-C` option for matching process names, and a `h` option to suppress headers, and `-o` to specify what output you want from `ps`.  e.g. `ps h -o pid -C "$APP_NAME"`

To summarise all that, use:

```
    PID=$(pgrep "$APP_NAME")
or
    PID=$(pgrep -f "$APP_NAME")
or
    PID=$(ps h -o pid -C "$APP_NAME")
```

BTW, if there is **any** chance of multiple PIDs being returned by `pgrep` or `ps`, you should capture the output into an array, not into a scalar variable.   For example, the following will capture the PIDs of all visible bash processes into the array `$BASHPIDS`.

```
$ BASHPIDS=( $(ps h -o pid -C bash) )

$ typeset -p BASHPIDS
declare -a BASHPIDS=([0]="68910" [1]="71059" [2]="71634" [3]="71641" [4]="71643"
[5]="71680" [6]="71683" [7]="71684" [8]="71687" [9]="71693" [10]="71712" [11]="72394"
[12]="72568" [13]="72589" [14]="970222" [15]="974740" [16]="1078757" [17]="1278073"
[18]="1365082" [19]="1405642" [20]="1458889" [21]="2278763" [22]="2466442" [23]="2876831"
[24]="2955565" [25]="3260896" [26]="3261235" [27]="3269020" [28]="3281961" [29]="3702104" 
[30]="4038149")
```

if, for some reason, you wanted to kill them all, you could do so with:

```
kill "${BASHPIDS[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

this command fix the problem:

```
 echo "${PID}" | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: If there's only one PID, a simple `kill -9 "$PID"` would do.

Comment: And if there are multiple PIDs, in this case only you can omit the double quotes, `kill -9 $PID`